# Create function, ignore the missing variables or declare the missing variables equal to NULL as default

Tags: r

I am writing a function that contains a few variables, some of them may not be defined/declared. How can they be automatically passed as "NULL"/ or being ignored as a default in case they are not defined/declared.

```
combine <- function(GroupOne, GroupTwo) {
                    paste(GroupOne, GroupTwo)}
```

For example 1, only define GroupOne

```
GroupOne <- "a"
```

Result

```
combine()
"a"
```

For example 2: define both GroupOne and GroupTwo

```
GroupOne <- "a"
GroupTwo <- "b"
```

Result

```
combine()
"ab"
```

I have tried to combine it with function "missing", "exists", "hasArg" but haven't been successful yet. I'd like to hear your insights!

Many thanks in advance and Cheers!

Comment: Obviously you haven't run any of the code shown in your question.  `print(combine)` would print the source code of the function, and `paste` with no further arguments will put a space character between the values.  Please spend a little more time writing your question.  It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry. My fault to simplify the actual scripts. I've corrected it :-)

Comment: Nope.  Did you actually run `combine()` in your R console?  Help people help you.  Jerry Maguire it.

Answer (score 1):

When building a function, you can set variables to NULL by default:

```
GroupOne <- "a"
GroupTwo <- "b"

combine <- function(GroupOne=NULL, GroupTwo=NULL){
  if(is.null(GroupOne) | is.null(GroupTwo)){
    paste0(GroupOne, GroupTwo)
  } else {
    paste(GroupOne, GroupTwo)
  }
}

combine()
character(0)

combine(GroupOne)
"a"

combine(GroupOne,GroupTwo)
"a b"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the following will do what you want.

```
combine <- function(GroupOne, GroupTwo) {
    if(missing(GroupOne)) GroupOne <- NULL
    if(missing(GroupTwo)) GroupTwo <- NULL
    paste(GroupOne, GroupTwo)
}

combine()
character(0)

GroupOne <- "a"
combine(GroupOne)
[1] "a "
```

Comment: I got this error 
 'missing' can only be used for arguments'
when applying your script

Comment: @BINewbies Works with me. (I had tested it.) Are you sure you've copied it and pasted as is? Both `GroupOne` and `GroupTwo` *are* arguments.